# Change product position by drag and drop?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog

I'm using magento 2.1 and I would like to know if there is an possibility that I can change the product **order position by dragging** in de back-end?

Comment: Explain question with detail. order you are use for fronted or admin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not change position of The product from admin side by dragging.
you can have access to set column position by dragging.

You can have options to **sort products** on base of column name.